# find command is not able to find piped file

Tags: delete, find, pipe, syslinux

I have a file named `.sock` in `/var/spool/` dir.

Here is the result of `ls -al /var/spool/`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root     root 121 Dec 16 09:55 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root     root 267 Dec 14 10:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root     root  63 Oct 28  2019 anacron
drwx------.  2 root     root   6 Feb 13  2019 cron
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root     root   6 Dec 14  2017 lpd
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root     mail  22 Dec 14 10:47 mail
prw-r--r--.  1 telegraf root   0 Dec 17 10:04 nethermind.sock
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root     root 201 Jul 29  2019 postfix
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root     root  19 Oct 28  2019 rhsm
drwx------.  2 root     root   6 Sep  6  2018 up2date
```

You can see the `nethermind.sock` file is marked as `prw-r--r--.`

I want to delete this file, so I write this in my script -

```
NETHERMIND_SOCK="/var/spool/nethermind.sock"
PARITY_SOCK="/var/spool/parity.sock"

if [ -f $NETHERMIND_SOCK ]; then
    rm -f $NETHERMIND_SOCK
elif [ -f $PARITY_SOCK ]; then
    rm -f $PARITY_SOCK
else
    echo ".sock not found"
fi
```

It always gives `.sock not found`
I tried then to find and delete like -

`sudo find / -type f -name "*.sock" -exec rm -f {} +`

But it seems that the file is not findable.

If I do `sudo find /var/spool/ -type f -name "nethermind.sock"`, It doesn't return anything.

I am not sure about mark `p` from here `prw-r--r--.`

Here is a [link](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/What-does-the-following-permissions-prw-rw-rw-mean-and-how-do-I/td-p/38587) actually what `p` marked means. But `find` command is not able to find piped file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your file isn't a regular file but a pipe you can't use `[ -f ...]` or `-type f`. Use `[ -p ... ]` opr `-type p` instead:

```
if [ -p $NETHERMIND_SOCK ]; then
    ....
```

or

```
sudo find / -type p -name "*.sock" ...
```